# Handler for fastcgi-script returned invalid result code 1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, jqgrid

When making an Ajax request that saves a record in database, the record is actually saved, but this is also saved in apache log:

```
[Thu Feb 02 22:38:11.135174 2017] [core:error] [pid 15509] [client 190.96.27.189:23385] AH00524: Handler for fastcgi-script returned invalid result code 1, referer: http://mutualcontratos.devx.cl/app_dev.php/contratos
```

What may be mean this?

I cannot post any code because the Ajax code is made under the scenes because is the JQGRID jquery grid. This error started happening suddenly, but I only see this error in error_log, because web user sees all works perfectly.

Comment: Without seeing your AJAX code it is literally impossible to tell you what is causing that error. Inspect the AJAX that gets generated in your debugger by setting breakpoints, and post the resulting AJAX code here.

Comment: How to do that? It is inside Jqgrid code so it is invisible for me. Besides that, it would be helpful if you or someone explains what does this error mean. By knowing what does the error mean is a good clue to see what is happening.